# Create a table observer

Tags: module, database, joomla-3.9

I am trying to create a table observer in a module. I am using the Table Advanced API guide in the Joomla documentation https://docs.joomla.org/Table_Advanced_API_Guide. When I use the code provided, the class MyObserver does not work. I have tried making the class abstract, and I have tried extending AbstractObserver instead of implementing JObserverInterface. When I try to make MyObserver abstract, then the createObserver function does not work. When I try to extend AbstractObserver, then it states that it cannot find the class AbstractObserver. How do I get the class MyObserver to work?

I am running Joomla 3.9.22 with PHP 7.0.33. My database is a MySQL version database 10.1.47-MariaDB-0+deb9u1.

myobserver.php

```
<?php
    
    defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
    
    class MyObserver implements JObserverInterface
    {
        // Usually you would define your class as
        // class MyObserver extends AbstractObserver
        // and then the $table variable and a basic constructor would be included for you
        protected $table;
        public function __construct($table)
        {
            $table->attachObserver($this);
            $this->table = $table;
            $observers = $table->getObserverOfClass("MyObserver");
            $observersClass = get_class($observers);
            echo "<br>In MyObserver constructor.<br>";
            echo "<br>Object returned from getObserverOfClass() has class {$observersClass}<br>";
        }
        
        public static function createObserver($table, $params = array())
        {
            $observer = new self($table);
            return $observer;
        }
    
        public function onAfterStore(&$result)
        {
            echo "<br>In observer onAfterStore()<br>";
            if ($result)
            {
                echo "Got table store method notification for table {$this->table->getTableName()}, id {$this->table->id}<br>";
            }
        }
    }
```

demomodules.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;
class TableDemoModules extends Table

{
protected $_jsonEncode = array('params');

    function __construct(&$db)
    {
        parent::__construct('#__modules', 'id', $db);
        require 'myobserver.php';
        MyObserver::createObserver($this);
    }
    
    function check()
    {
        $this->note .= " added via module";
    }
    
    protected function _getAssetName()
    {
        return "com_modules.module." . $this->id;
    }
    
    protected function _getAssetTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
    
    protected function _getAssetParentId(Table $table = null, $id = null)
    {
        $assets = self::getInstance('Asset', 'JTable', array('dbo' => $this->getDbo()));
        $assets->load(array("name" => "com_modules"));
        return $assets->id;
    }
}
```

mod_advanced_table.php

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted Access');

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Table;

$app = Factory::getApplication();
$input = $app->input;
$user = Factory::getUser();

echo "Module id is {$module->id}<br>";

// Tell Joomla to look in the current (module) directory for our table class file
Table::addIncludePath(__DIR__);
$moduleTable = Table::getInstance('DemoModules', 'Table', array());

if ($moduleTable->load($module->id))
{
    echo "<br>Module title is {$moduleTable->title}<br>";
    // checkout/checkin
    if ($moduleTable->isCheckedOut($user->id))
    {
        echo "<br>module record isCheckedOut call returned true<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>module record isCheckedOut call returned false<br>";
    }
    // ACL rules
    if ($rules = $moduleTable->getRules())
    {
        $rulesString = (string) $rules;
        echo "<br>ACL Rules: $rulesString <br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<br>getRules() didn't return anything<br>";
    }
    $userGroups = $user->getAuthorisedGroups();
    $randomIndex = array_rand($userGroups);
    $newRule = array("core.edit" => array($userGroups[$randomIndex] => 1));
    echo "Setting rules to " . json_encode($newRule) . "<br>";
    $moduleTable->setRules($newRule);
    $moduleTable->store();
    // ordering
    $where = 'POSITION = "' . $moduleTable->position . '"';
    echo "<br>Next order value: " . $moduleTable->getNextOrder($where) . "<br>";
    
    $moduleTable->move(2, $where);
    echo "Ordering value is now: {$moduleTable->ordering}<br>";
    
    $where .= " and published = 1";
    $moduleTable->reorder($where);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was working ok on my instance Joomla 3.9.22 with PHP 7.3.5 (and mysql). Then to test this I selected PHP 7.0.33 instead and it gave me an error:

`Fatal error: Declaration of MyObserver::createObserver($table, $params = Array) must be compatible with JObserverInterface::createObserver(JObservableInterface $observableObject, $params = Array) in C:\wamp64\www\...\modules\mod_advanced_table\myobserver.php on line 5`

I managed to fix the problem by replacing

```
public static function createObserver($table, $params = array())
```

with

```
public static function createObserver(JObservableInterface $table, $params = array())
```

(Alternative if you can upgrade your version of php this problem might right itself).

Incidentally, you can define your class using

```
class MyObserver extends AbstractObserver
```

but you would have to precede that with:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Table\Observer\AbstractObserver;
```

Can you let me know if this fixes things as I'd like to update the Joomla documentation on that page with this issue.

Comment: Adding JObservableInterface to the function worked for me. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation. I've updated that Joomla docs page now.